# Windows Server 2019 storage space shows wildly different values for size vs size on disk

Tags: storage-spaces, windows-server-2019, refs

So I'm running Windows Server 2019. I've got two 10 TB disks connected together into a storage pool. I've then created a single volume that takes up that entire pool. I do have deduplication turned on, and it's showing a Deduplication Rate of 14%. The volume is formatted with ReFS.

My question is surrounding the size vs size on disk values reported in Windows Explorer. If I look at the entire volume as a whole, it shows a capacity of 18.2 TB with 11.9TB of free space. Great. If I open the drive in Windows explorer and select everything and hit properties, I get the following:

[image: sizes_are_hard]

Obviously those are not very close. Most of the subfolders on this drive show something similar: a size on disk of <0.1% of the size.

I also ran WinDirStat on the whole drive and got the 5.56 GB value. I've read some of the reasons behind why Size and Size on disk can differ, but none of them seem to apply here. Can anyone tell me what's going on here and help me get a good tree/graph of real disk usage per folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the deduplication service was causing my storage confusion. Most of the files are allocated elsewhere on the disk: in the deduplication system's storage area. I couldn't find a setting for WinDirStat to use the size instead of the size on disk. WizTree worked fine and I was able to get a good idea of what was taking up space on my disk.